# Hue Database 111 Error

Tags: mysql, hue

I have been trying to set up hue to an external mysql database & it fails with below error when I try to do a

```
sudo -u hue hue/build/env/bin/hue dumpdata > tmp.json
```

mysql host is 127.0.1.1

I granted privileges to hue user using command:
grant all on hue.* to 'hue'@'%' identified by '123';

`in pseudo-distributed.ini i made the following changes in [database] section:`

```
engine=mysql
host=127.0.1.1
port=3306
user=hue
password=123
name=hue
## options={}
```

& yet it fails with below error:

```
File "hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('desktop==3.7.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 60, in entry
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 231, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 415, in get_server_version
    self.cursor().close()
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 317, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vamsi/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 188, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.1.1' (111)")
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I am ready for a team viewer interaction too, if someone could solve this issue for me.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the mysql database from the command line ..

Comment: Did you try with 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.1.1?